# Break-up Chapter Header in two or more lines

Tags: chapters

In the code below, if a chapter heading is too long, the text does not fit on the page.  I wanted help to get the header text to appear on two (or more lines) if the chapter header gets too long.

For the example code given below, the chapter named, "List of Matlab Algorithms" is the problematic chapter.  Can you help me have the chapter appear like:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{%
  \fontsize{60}{130}\color{myblueii}\scshape\bfseries%
}

\newcommand\chapnamefont{%
  \normalfont\color{white}\scshape\small\bfseries
}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=13cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {\thechapter};%
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {\chapnumfont #1};
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=13cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {};%
  \node[
      anchor=south east,minimum width=2in,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {\chapnumfont #1};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{Problem}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Problem Statement 1}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{List of Matlab Algorithms}
\section{Algorithm 1}
\lipsum[1]

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\leftmark}{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \appendixname~\thechapter}
\appendix
\chapter{References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: add option `text width=<some length>` to `\node[
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {\chapnumfont #1};`

Comment: @touhami,  Thanks for your input.  I was able to get the chapter heading into two lines, but the spacing between line 1 and line 2 is almost non-existent.  Can you tell me how to increase the line spacing when the chapter heading is in two lines?  Also, how to right justify the chapter heading, when the headings are in two lines like that shown in the graphic?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution.
[image]

1. to allow line break use `text width=.6\paperwidth`
2. alignement with `align=right`
3. interlines space use font option `font=\chapnumfont`

**Note 1** I redefine `\chapnumfont`:

```
\newcommand\chapnumfont{%
      \fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{myblueii}\bfseries%
    }
```

here fontsize : 60pt and interline 72pt that make interline=1.2* fontsize

**Note 2**  you have to complete the change for numberless (starred) chapters if needed.

---

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{%
  \fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{myblueii}\bfseries%
}

\newcommand\chapnamefont{%
  \normalfont\color{white}\scshape\small\bfseries
}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=13cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {\thechapter};%
    {};
  \node[
      text width=.6\paperwidth, align=right, font=\chapnumfont,
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {#1};
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=13cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {};%
  \node[
      anchor=south east,minimum width=2in,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {\chapnumfont #1};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{Problem}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Problem Statement 1}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{List of Matlab Algorithms}
\section{Algorithm 1}
\lipsum[1]

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\leftmark}{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \appendixname~\thechapter}
\appendix
\chapter{References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: THANK YOU for your help!  Sincerely appreciated!  I changed the font to `\scshape` and now the line splits up as (line 1) List of Mat-                                 (line 2) lab Algorithms.  Is there a way to get "List of Matlab" on one line, and "Algorithms" on the other line while using the `\scshape` font?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry `\scshape` Deleted unintentionally. Try with `text width=.7\paperwidth`