# Break-up Chapter Header in two or more lines part 2

Tags: chapters

This post is building from the post found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301284/break-up-chapter-header-in-two-or-more-lines).  Plese help me develop a solution  where the "numberless" chapters like the `List of Algorithms` and `List of Matlab Codes` be displayed as:

- Line 1   List of
- Line 2   Algorithms

Instead of showing up as:

- Line 1   List of Al-
- Line 2   gorithms

and

- Line 1   List of
- Line 2   Matlab Codes

Instead of showing up as:

- Line 1   List of Mat-
- Line 2   lab Codes

This should not affect the way how the other chapter headers are currently displayed.  That is, the words are not split up into two lines like "Mat-lab".

I tried adjusting the code `text width=.72\paperwidth` but still could not come up with a satisfactory solution without disrupting the other chapter headers.

I basically do not want the words to be split up in the chapter headers.  Thanks for your time and help.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{%
  \fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{myblueii}\scshape\bfseries%
}

\newcommand\chapnamefont{%
  \normalfont\color{white}\scshape\small\bfseries
}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=13cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {\thechapter};%
    {};
  \node[
      text width=.7\paperwidth,
      align=right,
      font=\chapnumfont,
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {#1};
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=13cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {};%
  \node[
      text width=0.7\paperwidth,
      align=right,
      font=\chapnumfont,
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-40pt]chaptop.south)
    {#1};
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Matlab Code}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s\\}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\lstlistoflistings

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Problem}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Problem Statement 1}
\lipsum[1]

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\leftmark}{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \appendixname~\thechapter}
\appendix
\chapter{References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can try `\chapter[List of Algorithms]{List of\\ Algorithms}`

Comment: @touhami, Thanks for your comment and potential solution.  I made a slight modification to the original question (I mistakenly left older code in the question). Sorry.  The chapter names are the names in the "numberless" chapters, like in the table of contents for `List of Matlab Codes` and `List of Algorithms`.  I have updated the question with the correct code of the relevant question being asked.  Sorry for the discrepancy!

Comment: in this case try `you can try \chapter*{List of\\ Algorithms}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure, if you want to have that automatically or not.

Because only the chapter headings have to changed if needed you can use for example the command `\mbox{...}`.  Command `\mbox` disallows an hyphenation of the included word `...`.  Another possibility could be just to add `\\`, but the you can get a problem with your table of content or headers, because you do not want there a line break.  Or if you use hyperref you will get an error message that `\\` is not allowed as an token in the bookmarks.

So you can do the following:

```
\chapter{List of \mbox{Matlab} Codes}
```

if you only want to disallow the hyphenation in `Matlab`.

Or you can use:

```
\chapter[List of Algorithms]{List of \mbox{Algorithms}}
```

then `[...]` is used for headers and table of contents and `{...}` is used for printing the chapter heading.

complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{%
  \fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{myblueii}\scshape\bfseries%
}

\newcommand\chapnamefont{%
  \normalfont\color{white}\scshape\small\bfseries
}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=13cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {\thechapter};%
    {};
  \node[
      text width=.7\paperwidth, 
      align=right, 
      font=\chapnumfont,
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {#1};
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=13cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {};%
  \node[
      text width=1\paperwidth,
      align=right,
      font=\chapnumfont,
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-40pt]chaptop.south)
    {#1};
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{Problem}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Problem Statement 1}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{List of \mbox{Matlab} Codes}
\section{Algorithm 1}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter[List of Algorithms]{List of \mbox{Algorithms}}
\section{Algorithm 1}
\lipsum[1]

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\leftmark}{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \appendixname~\thechapter}
\appendix
\chapter{References}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result of one page]

**Update:**

If you want to that automatically you can use the to lines

```
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=10000
```

to suppress the hyphenating in the chapter name.  See the following MWE where to add it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{%
  \fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{myblueii}\scshape\bfseries%
}

\newcommand\chapnamefont{%
  \normalfont\color{white}\scshape\small\bfseries
}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {% <==============================================================
  \hyphenpenalty=10000
  \exhyphenpenalty=10000
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=13cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {\thechapter};%
    {};
  \node[
      text width=.7\paperwidth, 
      align=right, 
      font=\chapnumfont,
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-20pt]chaptop.south)
    {#1};
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {% <======================================================================
  \hyphenpenalty10000
  \exhyphenpenalty10000
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[myblueiii]
    (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
  \node[
      fill=mybluei,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=6cm,
      text depth=13cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (chaptop)
    {};%
  \node[
      text width=1\paperwidth,
      align=right,
      font=\chapnumfont,
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (chapnum) at ([xshift=-40pt]chaptop.south)
    {#1};
    {};
  \node[
      anchor=south,
      inner sep=0pt] (chapname) at ([yshift=2pt]chapnum.south)
  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{Problem}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Problem Statement 1}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{List of Matlab Codes}
%\chapter{List of \mbox{Matlab} Codes}
\section{Algorithm 1}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{List of Algorithms}
%\chapter[List of Algorithms]{List of \mbox{Algorithms}}
\section{Algorithm 1}
\lipsum[1]

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\leftmark}{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \appendixname~\thechapter}
\appendix
\chapter{References}

\end{document}
```

The result is the as showed above ...

Comment: I made a modification to the original question.  Please see updated question.  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe Please see my update!